Get n-th item from multi-dimensional array (python)
I have a tensor of shape (12, 19601, 1000) and I want to just take every n-th element of the second entry, I want a tensor of size (12, 19601 / n, 1000). Is there an efficient way to do this? Eventually the tensors will be much larger so the quicker the better. Thanks in advance

Why not use slices for the index?
import torch
x = torch.ones((12, 1024, 10))
x[:, ::2, :].shape  # torch.Size([12, 512, 10])
x[:, ::4, :].shape  # torch.Size([12, 256, 10])

See Tensor Indexing API.
